# Using Rules and Requests in Scrapy throws exception TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'callback'

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a beginner in scrapy, and I have been trying to do the following workflow: Start from page `A`, which is a result search page containing links for full articles whose url end is a digit. My intention is to grab each link of each result search page, access the links and scrap the full article.

I iterate over each page collecting links with the following rule:

```
   rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'\d+',)), callback='parse_short_story',follow=True),)
```

Each ensures that the last digit of the search page iterates to the next one after I am done collecting the links and scrapping the full articles of the current page.

The `parse_short_story` method merely uses a select to filter the portion of the html page which, and afterwards loops over the remaining portion to acquire the links of the full stories and pass it on for the request:

```
for short_story in short_stories:
        item = DmozItem()

        full_story_link = short_story.select(".//h2/a/@href").extract()

        if full_story_link:
            yield Request(full_story_link, self.parse_full_story, callback='self.parse_full_story', errback=lambda _: item, meta=dict(item=item),)            

        items.append(item)
    return items
```

On my understanding from the [tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) of scrapy, I need to return the items by the end of the parser methods, so that the rule properly append in a final list of items which I can throw in a json file or something else on running by the console. Notice this portion below of Response and return calls which crashes.  I can't figure out how to use both the Request and the return items.

The method `parse_full_story` gets the `response` parameter like the `parse_short_story` does, and recover the item I send as parameter with

```
    item = response.meta.get('item')
```

After properly setting the information I desired on my item `item` I use `return item`.

In summary,

My expectation were that the rule would take care of moving along the search pages containing the links of the full article using the callback of `parse_short_story`, while for each link of each page, the `parse_full_story` would access the full articles of those links, scrap what I wanted, add to the `item` item, and exit, hopefully scanning all full articles in the end.

Apparently my understanding is wrong and I get the error:

 `yield Request(full_story_link, self.parse_full_story, callback='self.parse_full_story', errback=lambda _: item, meta=dict(item=item),)
    exceptions.TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'callback'`

You can find the full runable code [here](http://gw.gd/JTol). As it runs, you will see that it keeps throwing the exception. If it is feasible to perform a direct fix and give/or a short explanation of what is wrong on this I would appreciate it, since similar problems lead me to Django associated questions on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Put only one callback parameter, use the `self.parse_full_story` (`Request()` expects a callable; [see here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects))

The "callback name string" version is only for Rules ([see here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.Rule))

Use

```
yield Request(full_story_link,
    self.parse_full_story,
    errback=lambda _: item,
    meta=dict(item=item),
)
```

instead of

```
yield Request(full_story_link,
    self.parse_full_story, callback='self.parse_full_story',
    errback=lambda _: item,
    meta=dict(item=item),
)
```